# What is the callback mechanism used when non-blocking version of connect() call is used in socket programming?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, nonblocking

In socket programming, let us say the server is listen for TCP connection on a particular port.
Now, on the client side, i create a *socket* and call *connect()* to establish a connection with the server. Note: the *connect()* API is called in non-blocking mode.

Since it is an non-blocking call and there is no callback method being passed when calling *connect()* API to be notified on completion of the event. So, i want to know **HOW** does the client gets to know when the TCP connection has been established successfully. So that it can initiate the data transfer?

Secondly part of the question - **WHEN**. Basically, for the TCP connection to be established, there should be 3 way handshake happening as below-

[image]

I assume, when the *connect()* API is called from client, *SYNC* packet is being sent from the client and connection establishment process is initiated. Since the *connect()* API is called in a non-blocking mode, it just initiates the connection by requesting the kernel and returns back the function call. And once the connection is successfully established the kernel has to notify the client saying - it is good to go and transfer the data. My confusion here is, the last phase is the 3 way handshake is completing at the server side (after the *ACK* packet is reached at the server), so how does the kernel at the client side be aware of the completion of the connection process?

Or is it like the kernel will notify the client process of the establishment of the connection as soon as it receives the *SYNC+ACK* from *Server* process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When non-blocking socket is used, `connect()` will usually return EINPROGRESS.

In that case, you can use `select()` function for waiting for connection establishment:
Set the socket to the write-set of the `select()` call.

When the connection is established/failed, select() will return and the write-set indicates that your socket is writable. Then you can call `getsockopt()` for getting result of the non blocking connect:

```
   if (getsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len) != -1)
       ...
```

Blocking TCP connect() returns when the client is received SYN-ACK.
And similar way with non-blocking TCP socket: select() returns when SYN-ACK is received:

[image]

There is little bit inaccuracy in the picture for making it more clear. I tried to illustrate slowness of the network by placing SYN after select call, and ACK after select return.

TCP-state of the client is change to ESTABLISHED when SYN-ACK is received. TCP-state of the server is change to ESTABLISHED when the ACK (of SYN-ACK) is received. So the client application can start sending data to the server before the server is returned from the `accept()` call. It is also possible that ACK (and retries) is lost in network, and the server never enter to the ESTABLISHED state.

Answer (score 6):

There is no callback mechanism. Callback mechanisms are associated with *asynchronous* I/O, in some APIs. Not with non-blocking I/O. And no, they aren't the same thing.

When a non-blocking `connect()` doesn't complete immediately, as it usually doesn't, otherwise what would be the point, it returns -1 with `errno` set to `EINPROGRESS`. You should then `select()` or `poll()` or `epoll()` the socket for writeability, an so on as described in [*man connect*](https://linux.die.net/man/2/connect). This is not, to restate the point, a callback mechanism. It is in fact a polling mechanism.

Comment: indeed it made me to understand that asynchronous call and non blocking call are two different thing.